# Visual Studio 2010 listing the same enum twice in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  In this question, `CardSet` is an enum declared in the "Entities" namespace.

When I start typing in "Car", if I hit tab the auto-completion always becomes `Entities.CardSet` instead of just `CardSet`.  This is occurring in a class method declared in the same namespace as the enum.

The enum is listed twice in Intellisense:

[image]

The source files for the enum and for the class being edited are in different folders.  `CardSet` is declared only once.  There is not a separate `CardSet` enumeration in a second namespace.

What is odd is code generated by "Implement abstract class" doesn't use the namespace - it correctly uses the shorter `CardSet`.

How can I get Visual Studio to get `Entities.CardSet` out of Intellisense so I can just type in
"Car +<kbd>Tab</kbd>"?  I have tried restarting Visual Studio to no effect.

Comment: It took me just a few minutes to notice the icons were different in Intellisense after asking this question.  I hadn't noticed them before now.  My only excuse is it's almost 2am.

Answer (score 2):

I just facepalmed.  It's because there's a property on the class *also* called CardSet.  I need to fix that.  I just noticed the icons in Intellisense are different: one is for a property while the other is for an enum.

Answer (score 2):

It's not listing the enum twice. It's listing two entries because there are two different things you might want to refer to: the `CardSet` property/field within your type, or the enum type itself (`Entities.CardSet`) to then refer to a specific member of the enum. Note how the icons are different.

The behaviour doesn't seem unreasonable to me - is it really affecting your productivity *that* much? If you really don't want to type all seven characters, just select the right value from the dropdown.

Comment: Take note that I already answered my own question.  And no, it isn't affecting my productivity *at all*.  Its just an annoyance and a curiosity.

Comment: @Inuyasha: I'd been writing my answer while you were posting yours - mine was posted a mere 25 seconds after yours :)